# How to render partial again and again(only with RenderAction)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, html.actionlink

How to render partial(with `Html.RenderPartial()`) again and again.

Or How to use `html.Action("","")` to render a partial (by calling an action which is returning  partial view ) again and again.

Comment: `Html.ActionLink(...)` has nothing to do with render `Partial` or `Action`. Did u mean `Html.Action(...)` or `Html.RenderAction(...)` ?.
Anyway just make a loop and put your Render helper in it something like @satish kumar answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you need to display ParialView many times on page. if this is your question then you have some thing like a collection which tells that how many time you want to render partialview on page. 
For Example
for(int i =0; i < 5;i++)
{
@Html.Partial("")
}
This will display an partial view 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `$.get()` or `$.ajax()`.

Place some html elements (`<div class='myclass'>`)

```
<div id='container>
  <div class='myclass' my-ajax-url='@Model.urlForWhatever' my-url-param='@Model.foo'>
  </div>

  <div class='myclass' my-ajax-url='@Model.urlForWhatever2' my-url-param='@Model.bar'>
  </div>

</div>
```

add something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var elems = $('.myclass').each(function () {
     // Perform Ajax call and render the output (contained in response)
     // the element is referreable using $(this) in the each function, so you can swap
     // its content via $(this).html().
     var url=$(this).attr('my-ajax-url') + '&param=' + $(this).attr('my-url-param');
     $.get(url, function(data) {
         $(this).html(data);
     });
  });
});
```

Ajax helper is good, but I found it somewhat limited for some kind of stuffs.
I prefer to store data inside DOM elements and then use jQuery for building up the urls (that piece of code is simplified, none would add a &name=value without checking it first)

PS: writing this without having the chance to test it, but should at least give an idea on how to do this.